# How to keep user input even after rerunning the program (JAVA)

Tags: java

I only started coding about a month ago and I am trying to add a code or program to my work in order to make it store user input and even after rerunning the program, the input will still be kept. Confused? For example, when you make an account on Facebook, they will keep your email and password so next time you just have to login without making the account again. Something like a database to store value I am guessing?

Comment: You need persistent storage.  This could be a database or something as simple as a text file depending on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a program terminates, it looses all the values stored in variables.

This is because we have a GC (Garbage Collection) mechanism which helps to clear up data which are not used.

In your case, to persist data post restart, we need to store to some external store (persistent storage) rather than keeping in the memory.

Your external store can be a database or can be a simple file.

Create a file and store your values in it. Once you restart the program, read the values again from it.

Comment: The cleaning up is usually done by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You would require a storage to store the data, as rerunning will erase all previous data. Any filesystem/db can be used to resolve your issue.